# Connect AWS Redis cache into multiple AWS account Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have created AWS Redis cache in AWS Account A and also able to connect in that account region Ec2 only.

How can i connect that Redis cache in across region and also across the Account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this ( considering Redis is accessible from VPC A )

1. Use VPC peering across account A VPC-A and account B VPC-B, you can follow the guide here [Peer with a VPC in another AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html).
2. Another alternative is to use transit gateway to have cross-account / region connectivity, This usually takes some time to build but if you are planning to extend your network to another account and another VPC's in the future will be beneficial